# Moving caret back/forward to previous/next editing position within a document in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, editor, navigation, xcode4, shortcut

In Xcode 3, I could go back to previous editing point within a document by pressing Command+Control+[Left|Right]. (I'm confusing it was Control or Option... However) In Xcode 4, the key combination is assigned to other feature. Code folding..? What did this key change into?

Comment: I have reported this to Apple's Radar. If you're looking for this feature, please report to Apple's Radar. Duplicated issue will increase issue's rating.

Answer (score 9):

The shortcut in XCode 4 for "Go forward/backward" is "Control" + "Command" + "Arrow"

This is super annoying for me.  When I tried to change the shortcut in the Shortcut Editor back to the Xcode 3 way, Xcode crashes.  Fun.

Comment: Control + Command + Arrow doesn't do the same as Command+Option+[Left|Right] did in Xcode 3, as it jumps between files, not to your previous editing point.

Comment: Actually, further usage of this shortcut seems to do what the Eonil is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for switching to Previous/Next editing position (Go Back/Go Forward) is using two finger swipe (left for Go Back, right for Go Forward).  I realize that this is not a keyboard shortcut but if you are using a Trackpad, it is much faster than trying to click on the buttons.

Note: The pointer does need to be in the editor for swiping to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean by "previous editing point", but Command+Option+Left|Right is code folding.  I use Option+Left|Right and Control+Left|Right to move back and forth within the code to get to particular points.

A list of Xcode keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Eonil is talking about "Go Forward/Go Backward" you can find under the View menu of Xcode 3, and the shortcuts are as he states, Cmd+Option+(Left|Right). Code folding is Ctrl+Cmd+(Left|Right).

Comment: Your answer is referring to moving the cursor per word, not to the last editing position.